# Disappearing UITableViewCell on UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I have a few UITableViewCells that I am loading from an XIB file. Everything is great until I call the [UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] method when the cell disappears. When I call [UITableView reloadData] everything loads find, when I scroll the cell on and off the view it will also reappear also. Weird.

I've also noticed that when I call [UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] the UITableView will not try to reuse a cached cell and will try to get a new one with cell = [tableViewCells objectAtIndex:cellId];

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    // the objects from the XIB files are loaded onto an NSArray instance variable at viewDidLoad
    tableViewCells = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int cellId = /* some logic to get the correct cellID */
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ProfileTableViewCell_%d", cellId];
    ProfileTableViewCell *cell = (ProfileTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [tableViewCells objectAtIndex:cellId];
        // additional work to setup subviews for the cell
        [cell prepareSubviews];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
}
```

and just in case here is some of the stuff I'm doing in [ProfileTableViewCell prepareSubviews]

```
- (void)prepareSubviews
{
    ...
    [self.containerView.layer setCornerRadius:3];
    [self.containerView.layer setBorderColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xCDCDCD).CGColor];
    [self.containerView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [self.containerView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.containerView.layer setShouldRasterize:NO];
    [self.containerView.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance to the awesome person that can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is your problem, but the way you get your cells is not the normal way. You should make each type of cell in its own nib (with a unique identifier), and then register the nibs with registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, just dequeue the cell you need based on the index path, and don't put anything in an if (cell == nil) clause, because that will not be invoked when you do it this way.

Comment: Agreed.  His code instantiates a single cell from a nib in viewDidLoad  but then potentially returns this same cell instance multiple times for different rows.  That is why cells are disappearing - the tableview is repositioning the same cell from one row to another.

Comment: Actually the ProfileTableViewCell.xib contains 6 different UITableViewCells with different reuse ids and I'm calling the appropriate one using cell = [tableViewCells objectAtIndex:cellId]; where cellId would be the index number of the object within the XIB. I thought I could save some overhead by loading a single xib containing all the cells I need apposed to loading 6 different XIBs. Now that I understand that this is something non-standard I might try a different approach. Non-standard logic always has glitches.

Comment: @JihoKang, The easiest way is to do it in a storyboard. You can make all 6 cells in one table view.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: doesn't work when you only need to change the height for a static cell.

Try to call just

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

As the documentation says:

> You can also use this method followed by the endUpdates method to
>   animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell.